# innoDB tablew are not showing after backup

Tags: mysql, windows-7, innodb

I recently had problems with my win 7 so I had to reinstall.... and I had to reinstall web server too with mysql

before I had mysql 5.1 now I have 5.5.

I have made a backup from
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data (copied directories of my databases)

and I've copied all the directories now to
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data

when checking the result I get only myisqm tables showing, there is no innodb tables!

SHOW ENGINES gives me this

```
FEDERATED   NO  Federated MySQL storage engine  NULL    NULL    NULL
MRG_MYISAM  YES Collection of identical MyISAM tables   NO  NO  NO
MyISAM  YES MyISAM storage engine   NO  NO  NO
BLACKHOLE   YES /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it...   NO  NO  NO
CSV YES CSV storage engine  NO  NO  NO
MEMORY  YES Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary...   NO  NO  NO
ARCHIVE YES Archive storage engine  NO  NO  NO
InnoDB  DEFAULT Supports transactions, row-level locking, and fore...   YES YES YES
PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA  YES Performance Schema  NO  NO  NO
```

So what should I do? I checked and relevant files ARE in the directories... f.e.

classifieds.frm
classifieds.MYD
classifieds.MYI

ok, I stop the mysql55 service, I override the files:
- ibdata1
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1

from my backup ... but when I re-start the service I get an error: The process terminated unexpectedly. when checking the log:

```
120429  9:52:29 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120429  9:52:29 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120429  9:52:29 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120429  9:52:29 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120429  9:52:29 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 59.0M
120429  9:52:29 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file .\ib_logfile0 is of different size 0 130023424 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 31457280 bytes!
120429  9:52:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
120429  9:52:29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
120429  9:52:29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: INNODB
120429  9:52:29 [ERROR] Aborting

120429  9:52:29 [Note] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you get that the InnoDB data files are there? I.e. files are named like this:
- ibdata1
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1

Then try to run from command line

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

then enter your password when prompted.

Comment: I checked those 3 files and were there, do I need to override these 3 files from the backup too?

Comment: These files are the data for your InnoDB tables. The .frm are the table structures only. So yes you will need these files from the backup.

Comment: You need to find the `.cnf` file that contains the inodb log file size and update to the actual one.

Comment: Look in your `my.cnf` configuration for a `innodb_log_file_size` variable. Add it if it doesn't exist, under the [mysqld] section (there is a line that says InnoDB is enabled by default, put it bellow). Set the  value  to `200M` to allow a bigger file size to be accepted. It should read: `innodb_log_file_size =200M`

Comment: I did change it to 200M but it doesn't help, stil the same error, now I am looking for cnf file

Comment: NO cnf files on my c: regarding MYSQL :(

Comment: the size should match, try 120M instead

Comment: Can I save just structure if not the data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, JScoobyCed suggested I change the size of the innodb_log_file_size in my.ini file...

after few tries I figured out the correct size.... in my case was innodb_log_file_size =124M since my backuped files ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 were about 126MB big

Thanks

I got my tables back, finally...

wooooo hooooo